# Proof that markov chain equilibrium using Farkas' lemma

Tags: markov-chains, linear-programming, nonlinear-optimization, duality-theorems

Given a transition matrix for markov chain $ P \in \mathbb R^{dxd} $ such that $$ P_{i,j} \geq 0,\quad
 1 \leq (i,j) \leq d, \quad
\sum_{j=1 \in d }P_{i,j} $$
and $i=1,....,d$.

Let $ x_{0}$ be probability vector and

$$ x_{0} \in \mathbb R^{d},\quad \sum_{j=1 \in  d} x_{i} =1, \quad x_{k+1} = Px_{k},\quad k \in \mathbb N_{0} $$

given that vector
$ x^{*}$ is an equilibrium such that

$$ Px^{*} =x^{*},\quad  x^{*}\geq 1 ,\quad \sum_{j=1 \in d } x_{i}^{*} = 1 .$$

I want to use Farkas' lemma to proof the existence of equilibrium vector $x^{*}$.

I'm assuming I should derive a system of equations that must be satisfied or otherwise $x_{0} \in $ some conic combination but I'm struggling to derive that

Comment: Try to improve the latex to make your question more readable. The column vector $v=(1/d,\ldots,1/d)^T$ satisfies $Pv=v$, I think you want $x^*$ to satisfy $x^*P=x^*$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $P$ be a $d \times d$  stochastic matrix, i.e., all the entries are nonnegative and
$\sum_{j=1}^d P_{ij}=1$ for all $i \in [1,d]$. The goal is to show there exists a probability vector $x \in {\mathbb R}^d$ so that
$P^Tx=x$. Let $A$ be the $d+1$ times $d$ matrix whose first $d$ rows coincide with $I-P^T$, and the last row of $A$ is the all ones vector.
Let $b \in {\mathbb R^{d+1}}$ be the vector consisting of $d$ zeros followed by a single $1$.
Then the goal is equivalent to proving existence of $x \in {\mathbb R^d}$ such that
$$x \ge 0\,, \qquad Ax=b \,.  \tag{1}$$
By Farkas' Lemma [1], it suffices to prove that there is no $y \in  
{\mathbb R^{d+1}}$ that satisfies the inequalities
$$A^Ty \ge 0 \,, \qquad    b^T y <0  \,. \tag{2} $$
The system $(2)$ can be rewritten as
$$(I-P)\widetilde{y}+y_{d+1}{\bf 1} \ge 0 \,, \qquad    y_{d+1} <0 \,, \tag{3}$$
where $\widetilde{y} \in {\mathbb R}^d$ is the projection of $y$ to the first $d$ coordinates, and ${\bf 1}$ is the all ones column vector of length $d$.
Suppose that $y \in   {\mathbb R^{d+1}}$ satisfies $(3)$ and
that $y_k=\min_{i \in [1,d]} y_i$. Then  any weighted average of $y_1,\ldots,y_d$ is at least $y_k$, so
$y_k-(P\widetilde{y})_k  \le 0$, and row $k$ of $(3)$ yields a contradiction. Since there is no solution to $(2)$, the goal $(1)$ must have a solution.

[1] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Farkas%27_lemma

Comment: thanks for the great answer. I'm just wondering did you use $b=[ 0,...0,1]$ to show that $y_{d+1} <0$ to complete the proof or was it for another reason. Also I'm not sure if the line before the last the inequality was supposed to be $y_{k}- (P_{y_{k}}) \leq 0$ instead or did I understand something incorrectly. Thanks again, that was really a very detailed answer.

Comment: Sorry I meant it should have been $y_{k} - (Py_{k}) \leq 0$.

Comment: t was $y_k-(P\widetilde{y})_k$,  where $(P\widetilde{y})_k$ is the $k$th element in the vector $P\widetilde{y}$ . Here $P\widetilde{y}$ is matrix times vector multiplication. There was a tilde missing in the answer before.

Answer (score 2):

Unraveling the proof of Farkas' lemma, we get a direct proof of the existence of a stationary distribution that is more intuitive.

**Claim:** Let $P$ be a $d \times d$  stochastic matrix, i.e., all the entries are nonnegative and
$\sum_{j=1}^d P_{ij}=1$ for all $i \in [1,d]$. Then there exists a probability row vector  $x \in {\mathbb R}^d$ so that
$xP=x$.

**Proof**:  Let $K$ be the simplex of probability row  vectors  in  ${\mathbb R}^d$, and let $e_i$ (a row vector) be the $i$th standard basis element in  ${\mathbb R}^d$.   Using compactness of $K$, choose   $x \in K$  that minimizes $\|x -xP\|_2$ and write $z= x -xP$. Suppose $z_i$ is the minimal entry in $z$, so that $$e_i(I-P)z^T =z_i- \sum_j P_{ij} z_j \le 0\,. \tag{*}
$$
Since $w:=\delta  e_i+(1-\delta)x \in K$ for any $0<\delta <1$, we have
$$\|z\|_2^2\le \|w(I-P)\|_2^2=\|\delta e_i(I-P)+(1-\delta)z\|_2^2=(1- \delta)^2\|z\|_2^2+2\delta e_i(I-P)z^T+O(\delta^2) \le 
(1-2\delta)  \|z \|_2^2 +O(\delta^2)\,,$$
using $(*)$ to obtain the last inequality.
Thus $2\delta \|z \|_2^2 =O(\delta^2)$, so $z=0$.